# Assign user to student role at system level

Tags: moodle

Assigning user to a custom role when user is confirmed. User is successfully assigned to a role. The role is a duplicate of default student role. When I login as user, I could see administrator homepage. I want the student front page when the user login.

```
if ($DB->record_exists("user", array('id' => $USER->id, 'confirmed' => '1' ))) {

    $context = CONTEXT_SYSTEM::instance($USER->id);
    role_assign($roleid, $USER->id, $context->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if new role has the capability `moodle/site:config` ?

Go to Site admin > Users > Permissions > Define roles > click the settings cog for [your new role]

Filter for capability `moodle/site:config`

I'm guessing you don't want that capability for the role?

Comment: @ Russel England - The moodle/site:config is set to "Not set" for the role.

Comment: @ Russel England - am I missing something in my code. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Can you post the url and/or screenshot of the admin page the user is seeing?

Comment: The frontpage has more than one html block, where each block has role permissions. Among these blocks, there is only one block designed for student role users and all other for administrator. When the student login, I should see the student block only.

Comment: okay, so you are not seeing the admin page :) but you are seeing an admin block. Can you add a screenshot please.

Comment: Here is a clone of homepage https://imgur.com/a/KtisuBx with a list of blocks. The 2nd block is for student role (block permissions given for student) where I wanted to show to students. When creating a new role, I choose ARCHETYPE: Student, where student is assigned to this role.

Comment: I don't recognise that block. Can you go to Site admin > Development > Debugging > then turn on debugstringids - then go to the url and either add ?strings=1 or &strings=1 - this will then show the source of the string. Can you tell me the source.

Comment: Thank You for all the support. I've set the capability view block to "Not Set " for the duplicate role. That was working fine now.